# Calculating pre-history of recursive filter from state space representation when optimising for initial z

Tags: infinite-impulse-response, state-space

For a recursive filter, suppose a set of $b$ and $a$ coefficients have been calculated. Assume a state-space representation for which an initial set of $z$-values have also been calculated as in Python's [lfilter_zi](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.lfilter_zi.html) function.

The author of [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27220671/matlab-filtfilt-function-implementation-in-java/52742099#52742099) demonstrates code that applies the filter using the state-space model.

We know that an equivalent filter representation is the recursive one

$y[n] = \sum_{i=1}^{N} a[i]y[n-i] + \sum_{i=0}^{N} b[i]x[n-i]$

My question is as follows: what are the pre-history values of $x$ and $y$ that, when used to cold-start the filter using the recursive formula, yield the same results as the application of the state-space model?

For example, for a 2nd order filter, I want to plug in the values of $x[-2]$, $x[-1]$, $y[-2]$ and $y[-1]$ in the recursive formula above for n=0 and n=1 and obtain the same results as when using the optimal $z$-values from the state-space model.

Comment: you can find those intial values of $y[-1]$, $y[-2]$, by running the filter backwards... But beware that filter initial conditions can refer to intermediate states and not necessarily output values.